# Market Close Order

Tags: stocks

The stock today traded on low volume all day. Then at 3:59 PM 58,000 shares were sold? I am confused as to what is going on and will this have an impact on the stock price tomorrow morning at the opening bell?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

During the day, market and limit orders are submitted at any time by market participants and there is a bid and an ask that move around over time.  Trades occur whenever a market order is submitted or a limit order is submitted that at a price that matches or exceeds an existing limit order.  If you submit a market order, it may consume all best-price limit orders and you can get multiple prices, changing the bid or ask at the same time.  All that stuff happens during the trading day only.

**What happens at the end of the day is different**.  A bunch of orders that were submitted during the day but marked as "on close" are aggregated with any outstanding limit orders to create a single closing price according to the algorithm established by the exchange.  Each exchange may handle the details of this closing event differently.  For example, the Nasdaq's [closing cross](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/083013/closing-cross-how-nasdaq-stock-prices-are-set.asp) or the NYSE's [closing auction](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/091113/auction-method-how-nyse-stock-prices-are-set.asp).

The close is the most liquid time of the day, so investors who are trading large amounts and not interested in intraday swings will often submit a market-on-close or limit-on-close order.  This minimizes their chance of affecting the price or crossing a big spread.  It's actually most relevant for smaller stocks, which may have too little volume during the day to make big trades, but have plenty at the close.  In short, **the volume you see is due to these on-close orders**.

The spike in volume most likely has no special information about what will happen overnight or the next day.  It's probably just a normal part of the market for illiquid stocks.